# Embed Facebook Posts in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, webview

I am trying to embed Facebook posts in my Android app's Webview. They show how to include the javascript in a website (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts)

I tried to load the html code into a webview like the following:

```
    String webcode = "<html>\n" +
            "   <body>\n" +
            "      <div class=\"fb-post\" \n" +
            "      data-href=\"https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/\"\n" +
            "      data-width=\"500\"></div>\n" +
            "      <!--        <div id=\"fb-root\"></div> -->\n" +
            "  </body>\n" +
            "<script>(function(d, s, id) {\n" +
            "  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];\n" +
            "  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;\n" +
            "  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;\n" +
            "  js.src = \"https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5\";\n" +
            "  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);\n" +
            "}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>\n" +
            "</html>";
    web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web_view.loadData(webcode, "text/html", null);
```

Java Script code in clear format:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="fb-post" 
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/"
      data-width="500"></div>
      <!--        <div id="fb-root"></div> -->
  </body>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</html>
```

However, the webview shows 2 lines of weird characters. If this code is ran on a server, the Facebook post is showing correctly. What needs to be done in order for this to work in an Android app's webview? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `web_view.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://some.url", webcode, "text/html", "utf-8", null);` instead of `web_view.loadData(webcode, "text/html", null);`